# Previous years registered: Excel COUNTIF and RETURN for X years

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, countif

UPDATED screenshot after attempting @Dude_Scott's suggestion:

[Desired output of data is in the blue table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcmiT.png)

Our data includes users who have registered between 1989-2016. 
All have registered at least once. 
Some register every year and some skip years. 
Our question is for each year, find how many years previous users registered. 
We want results to be 0yr, 1yr, 2yr, 3yr, etc., for each year. 
Arrays are working correctly.

I've organized the data structure in Excel this way:

1) UserID All Years

[image]

For year 1989, result is 0, since it was the first year of data collection.

For year 1990, this formula returns the expected count:

`=COUNT(IF($B$2:$B$11613=1989,1/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11613,$A$2:$A$11613,$B$2:$B$11613,1989)))`

Beginning with year 1991 is where I am tripped up: I can't find for multiple years. 
This formula is not working:

```
=COUNT(IF(AND(OR($B$2:$B$11613=1989,1990,1/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11613,$A$2:$A$11613,$B$2:$B$11613,1989,1990)))))
```

Where do I argue "COUNTIF 0 yr, 1 yr, 2 yr", etc. Thanks in advance. --f66

Comment: Have you tried writing a VBA function to do this?

Comment: This question is well suited to Python. If you uploaded your file I will show you a solution

Comment: @KolaB, no. I've tried SQL and Access.

Comment: @worm, working on how to figure out how to upload file...stay tuned.

Comment: If the registration year doesn't have duplicates per User ID, what's wrong with just `COUNTIFS()`?

Answer (score 0):

Since your using COUNTIF, I'm assuming you can use SUMPRODUCT also. In the below screen shot I am using this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$11=$D3)*($B$2:$B$11<=F$2))&" yr"
```

Without a sample of the workbook its a little difficult to determine what the output of your data should look like, but give it a go.

Side note, I would suggest updating the User ID and Years into a table format and giving it a named range, so you don't iterate though tens of thousands of lines with the array formula.

[image]

Comment: I see what you are doing here. I added a column of Years Previously Registered. The calculation is still off. It is not counting users from 1990, which should be 999. See updated comment for another screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

I may be reading this all wrong, but this seems to be a straightforward use case for a pivot table!

1. Select your data range
2. Set USERID as your row headings
3. Set YEARS as your column headings
4. Set `count of USERID` as your values

I do not use excel anymore, but below is a link to output for doing this with test data on google sheets.

[image: Google sheets pivot table for dummy data]

Comment: Your approach is straightforward, @KolB, but a pivot table does not work for the results I need. I need to calculate previous years registered for each year, not just a straight count of users each year. I added a screenshot to my original post at the top.